# Highlight active menu link in php

Tags: php, menu

I have made a navigation in php, which works perfect, well, almost perfect. I have 6 pages site and button of active page is highlighted with a different color. In 4 pages it works, but for "gold going green" and "About Ecuador" link remains not highlighted. Here is the code I used:

```
<?php 
//initialize the page variables here so no errors occur in some server environments
$index="myButtons";
$about="myButtons";
$gold="myButtons";
$ecuador="myButtons";
$contact="myButtons";
$documents="myButtons";
//this line gets the file name without the dot and extension

$menuLinkid=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");
if($menuLinkid=="index"){
$index='myActiveButton';
} else if($menuLinkid=="about"){
$about='myActiveButton';
} else if($menuLinkid=="gold"){
$gold='myActiveButton';
} else if($menuLinkid=="ecuador"){
$ecuador='myActiveLink';
} else if($menuLinkid=="contact"){
$contact='myActiveButton';
} else if($menuLinkid=="documents"){
$documents='myActiveButton';
}
?>

<div id="header">
<div id="innerheader">
<h1 id="logo"><a href="../index.php"><img src="img/logo.gif" /></a></h1>
<nav id="navigation">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a class="<?php echo $index; ?>" href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
<li>/</li>
<li><a class="<?php echo $about; ?>" href="../about.php">About</a></li>
<li>/</li>
<li><a class="<?php echo $gold; ?>" href="../gold-going-green.php">Gold going green</a>   </li>
<li>/</li>
<li><a class="<?php echo $ecuador; ?>" href="../about-ecuador.php">About Ecuador</a></li>
<li>/</li>
<li><a class="<?php echo $contact; ?>" href="../contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<li>/</li>
<li><a class="<?php echo $documents; ?>" href="../documents.php">Documents</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div><!-- /innerheader -->
</div><!-- /header -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You set everthing to 'myActiveButton', and use myActiveLink for ecuador:

```
$ecuador='myActiveLink';
```

Try this:

```
$ecuador='myActiveButton';
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what caused the problem and I made the change already.

Comment: Glad it worked! Feel free to upvote and/or select my answer then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
else if($menuLinkid=="gold"){
$gold='myActiveButton';
```

to

```
else if($menuLinkid=="gold-going-green"){
    $gold='myActiveButton';
```

& Change

```
$ecuador='myActiveLink';
```

to

```
 $ecuador='myActiveButton';
```

and recheck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Renku, I have not checked these two lines properly. Now it works. Much appreciate your help!